# JPA 2 Query Returning Incomplete Results

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql

The following query is only matching the first value found in the select subquery, even though there are match for all values `SELECT p FROM Profile p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT u.group FROM User u WHERE u.id = ?1)`

The subquery returns a comma separated list like: `1,2,3`. The query should return matches for all three subquery select results. Anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the table structure? It seems like User.id should be your primary key. Your subquery is filtering on that, so it would seem you would only get one result.

Comment: You're correct; there is (and should be) only one result. However, that result is a comma separated string. So the subquery for `u.group` should return `1,2,3`. Then the query should be `select p from Profile p where p.id in (1,2,3)`... Which in-turn should return multiple results.

Comment: So, your u.group value is '1,2,3'? Never really a good idea to use comma separated values within a database field. This would speak to needing a different structure in your database.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` clause doesn't work this way neither in JPQL nor SQL.

Value inside `(..)` is not a "comma separated string", it's a list of values. This list can be specified literally as a comma separated string, or it can be produced by subquery, as in your case. That is, condition in your query works as `p.id IN ("1,2,3")` (rather than `p.id IN (1,2,3)`), so it doesn't produce the desired result.

So, you can't use power of query languages (JPQL or SQL) to write queries against denormalized schema (your column contains a list of values, therefore it violates [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)). If you have many-to-many relation between `Profile`s and `User`s, express it as many-to-many relation with intermediate join table.

Answer (score 1):

While the `IN` operator supports comparison against the results of a *subquery*, what you're doing can't work (and I'm surprised that you even get one result). Before going further, let me quote the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 4.6.9 In Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator [NOT] IN in a
>   conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
>  in_expression ::=
>     {state_field_path_expression | type_discriminator} [NOT] IN
>         { ( in_item {, in_item}* ) | (subquery) | collection_valued_input_parameter }
> in_item ::= literal | single_valued_input_parameter
> ```
>
> The *state_field_path_expression*
>   must have a string, numeric, date,
>   time, timestamp, or enum value.
>
> The literal and/or input parameter
>   values must be *like* the same
>   abstract schema type of the
>   *state_field_path_expression* in type. (See Section 4.12).
>
> **The results of the subquery must be
>   *like* the same abstract schema type of the
>   *state_field_path_expression* in type**. Subqueries are discussed in
>   Section 4.6.16.
>
> Examples:
>
> `o.country IN (’UK’, ’US’, ’France’)`
>   is true for `UK` and false for `Peru`,
>   and is equivalent to the expression
>   `(o.country = ’UK’) OR (o.country =
>   ’US’) OR (o.country = ’ France’)`.
>
> `o.country NOT IN (’UK’, ’US’,
>   ’France’)` is false for `UK` and true
>   for `Peru`, and is equivalent to the
>   expression `NOT ((o.country = ’UK’) OR
>   (o.country = ’US’) OR (o.country =
>   ’France’))`.
>
> There must be at least one element in
>   the comma separated list that defines
>   the set of values for the `IN`
>   expression.
>
> If the value of a
>   *state_field_path_expression* or *in_item* in an IN or NOT IN expression is `NULL` or unknown, the
>   value of the expression is unknown.
>
> Note that use of a collection-valued
>   input parameter will mean that a
>   static query cannot be precompiled.

So, first, `p.id` doesn't match the return type of the subselect (which is actually a "minor" issue).

Second, and this is a major issue and misunderstanding, your query won't result in something like this (using "pseudo code"):

```
p.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

which is what you'd like - but in

```
p.id IN (’1,2,3’)
```

which obviously is not what you want, and won't work.

My only advice: normarlize your database.